# SFTranscriptionSegment's timestamp is always 0

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition, ios10

This is a questoin regarding new iOS 10 Speech framework.
I get the speech recognition result using following method

```
 recognitionTask =   [speechRecgzr recognitionTaskWithRequest:recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    }
```

But the timestamp of each SFTranscriptionSegment in result is 0 and also confidence is always 0

What can be the problem here? Have apple not implemented the API properly yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After few weeks I found that by setting this I can get timestamp and confidence:

```
speechRecgzr.defaultTaskHint = SFSpeechRecognitionTaskHintDictation;
```

Comment: Hi, im having the exact same problem, bit this didn't fix my issue. Did you maybe change anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5+

```
speechRecgzr.defaultTaskHint = .dictation
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and found that the `timestamp` and `duration` are always zero on partial results, but are set correctly on final results.

Check `isFinal` on your [`SFSpeechRecognitionResult`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionresult) instance. If that's `true`, then the transcription segments will have this metadata.

If you only want to deal with final results, you can set `shouldReportPartialResults` to `false` on your [`SFSpeechRecognitionRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest).