# Speech API - confidence always 0

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I tried using the official Apple example:
[SpeekToMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

I edited the example in the following way to get the confidence levels:

```
        if let result = result {
            for t in result.transcriptions
            {
                for s in t.segments
                {
                    print("POSSIBLE TRANSCRIPTION: \(s.substring) confidence: \(s.confidence)")
                }

            }
            self.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            isFinal = result.isFinal
        }
```

Problem is the confidence levels are always = 0.

I found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358599/sftranscriptionsegments-timestamp-is-always-0) but setting the defaultTaskHint to dictation (or anything else) didn't help.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the proper confidence values?

Comment: I find that as long as ```result.isFinal=false```, confidence is ```0.0``` but once it's ```true```, I get different values. You will need to call ```audioEngine.stop()``` to do that (as far as I know)

Comment: Same problem here. However, I sometimes get non-zero `confidence` values when `isFinal` is still `false`.