# SFTranscriptionSegment timestamp behaves differently in Simulator and iPhone - not returning seconds

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, ios17

I'm using the Speech framework to recognize words from live audio via the phone's mic input following [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio). Everything works great and I can see a live transcript. I would like to recognize segments of spoken text, i.e. recognize breaks and divide the transcript into chunks.

My problem is that the `SFTranscriptionSegment.timestamp` value behaves differently in the simulator and on a real device. To show what I mean, I created the following recognition handler:

```swift
nonisolated private func recognitionHandler(audioEngine: AVAudioEngine, result: SFSpeechRecognitionResult?, error: Error?) {
        let receivedFinalResult = result?.isFinal ?? false
        let receivedError = error != nil
        
        if receivedFinalResult || receivedError {
            audioEngine.stop()
            audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        }
        
        if let result {
            transcribe(result.bestTranscription)
            print("Last word timestamp:", result.bestTranscription.segments.last?.timestamp) // <-- this generates the output
        }
    }
```

Simulator Output (Set to iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 17.2):

```
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: Hello
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: this
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: is
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: a
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: test
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: test
Last word timestamp: Optional(1.1400000000000001) // <-- this is great because it's in seconds and it's called before the recording stops
```

iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 17.2:

```
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.0)
segment: Hello
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.01)
segment: this
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.02)
segment: is
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.03)
segment: the
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.03)
segment: a
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.04)
segment: test
recording stopped
Transcript: Hello this is a test
Last word timestamp: Optional(0.66) // <-- this is bad because it's not reported until the recording stops. Also, it's the first value in seconds (see difference to previous values 0.04 vs. 0.66)
```

### Issues:

1. On the physical device, you can see that the indicated values range from 0.0 to 0.04. This is not seconds even though the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sftranscriptionsegment/1649533-timestamp) say it should be. The real second value shows up once the recording is stopped (= 0.66 sec). How can I retrieve the real second value during the recording? This works fine in the simulator.
2. In the simulator, I receive the TimeInterval in seconds every time I stop speaking. This is the behavior I want, it allows me to recognize chunks. However, on the physical device, it doesn't seem to report any TimeIntervals in seconds until I actually stop the recording.
3. Btw, it's a common issue to see 0.0 sec values. This is a well-known behavior for unfinished segments, reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358599/sftranscriptionsegments-timestamp-is-always-0) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/62116). I can work around this by ignoring 0.0 segments, this works in the simulator because it still receives segments that indicate the real second value.

### TL;DR:

How can I get the `TimeInterval` in seconds of a `SFTranscriptionSegment` on a physical device?